# Using Django annotate(Count) with a nullable ForeignKey

Tags: django

Using the example Models from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

I want to do something like the following:

```
q = Entry.objects.filter(...)
entries = q.all().order_by('pub_date')
blog_counts = q.values('blog__name').annotate(Count('blog'))
```

This gives me back a result like the following:

```
[{'blog__count': 3, 'blog__name': u'Cheddar Talk'}, {'blog__count': 5, 'blog__name': u'Beatles Blog'}]
```

If the Entry.blog ForeignKey is made "null=True, blank=True", and I create several Entry records with a null value for blog, I get something like this:

```
[{'blog__count: 0, 'blog__name': None}, {'blog__count': 3, 'blog__name': u'Cheddar Talk'}, {'blog__count': 5, 'blog__name': u'Beatles Blog'}]
```

I expected to get the actual number of entries with no Blog associated, not 0. Looking at the SQL executed, I see that it is doing COUNT(`blog`.`id`) instead of something like COUNT(`entry`.`blog_id`), but changing to .annotate(Count('blog_id')) gives me:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'blog_id' into field.
```

What can I do to get an accurate count of Entries without an associated Blog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Entry.objects.filter(blog__isnull=True).count()
```

That will give you what you want. In your current code, Count is giving you exactly what you asked for, the number of blogs each entry is associated with. In the case of the ones with null blogs, that's zero, obviously.

Comment: Also, if you had your heart set on using annotate, you may be able to get away with `Count('blog__blog_id')` I don't play much with annotate so I'm not sure if that will work or not.

Comment: It wouldn't. `blog_id` would have to be an attribute of `Blog`. It's not, so that will raise an exception.

Comment: The idea is to get an accurate count for each Blog, as well as a count for the entries which have no associated Blog. Retrieving the count for the null values separately would work, but I'd still have to ignore the 0 count in the list. It seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: Bryce, the type of COUNT() I'm looking for would intuitively be made by something more like Count('entry__blog_id'), but that doesn't work either.

Comment: `Count` is a bit of a headache. Documentation says simply that it counts the number "related objects". It's usage is obvious with something like a ManyToManyField or even the reverse relation of a foreign key (`Blog.objects.annotate(Count(entry))`). It literally counts the related objects. On a forward relation of a foreign key, it takes an alternate behavior of counting instances of objects with the same value for that foreign key. The problem is that the methodology used to do that treats NULL as non-countable, resulting in your `0`s.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to get around that, since it's most likely a database-layer constraint.

Answer (score 9):

The generated SQL statement uses count clause in the form of `Count(<field_name>)` which does not count nulls. Unfortunately (at least **MySQL** and **PostgreSQL**) backends include null values into output even though nulls are not counted! Which leaves the user with a false impression that there are no null values at all.

**Solution**

The generated SQL statement must be in the form `Count(*)` instead of `Count(<field_name>)`. This will result in correct count of nulls.

```
blog_counts = q.values('blog__name').annotate(Count('*'))
```

See ticket:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15183